# Who do these lines tell about?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, literature

> My name is the first, third, and last of my name,
>   Or first, fifth, and sixth; that is quite all the same.
>   Take first, second, sixth, and again you will see:
>   My first, fifth, and last can also name me.

Who am I?

Hint:

> There is a clue in the title of this post.

Comment: I think you are DLosc.

Comment: @Gendarme Doubt it. Does your birth certificate say "Gendarme"? =P

Comment: Perhaps the first line means the first, third, and last letter of "my name", which comes out to say mne, am I on the right track?

Comment: @SimpleArt Clever idea, but no--"my name" should not be treated as if it's in quotation marks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might be:

> Philip Pirrip (aka Pip) from Dickens' Great Expectations

Because:

My name is the first, third, and last of my name,

> **P**h**i**lip Pirri**p** = Pip

Or first, fifth, and sixth; that is quite all the same.

> **P**hil**ip** Pirrip = Pip

Take first, second, sixth, and again you will see:

> Philip **Pi**rri**p** = Pip

My first, fifth, and last can also name me.

> **P**hil**i**p Pirri**p** = Pip

The hint in the title of the post is:

> Who do these lin**es tell a**bout?  = Estella Havisham, Pip's fellow orphan and love interest

Comment: By jove I think you've got it!

Answer (score 8):

Second guess

You are

> Dee Dee, Dexter's hyperactive older sister ([Dexter's Laboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter's_Laboratory))

Since

> all given arrangements (ignoring the space as a character) yield Dee.

Comment: Oh dear. Also not the intended answer, but it fits so well. There is, however, a clue in the title that will (hopefully!) narrow things down.

Comment: @DLosc, Hmm, does not seem to work for William Tell. "Lines Tell about" would be, what, lletsenil - that can't be it. Who, Dr Who? Estelle? No and no, oh well I think I'm *stuck*; someone will get it :)

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a slicker, more cunning solution, but here goes...

You are

> [Emmeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmeline_%28given_name%29)

My name is the first, third, and last of my name

> Eme

Or first, fifth, and sixth; that is quite all the same.

> Eli

Take first, second, sixth

> Eli

and again you will see:
My first, fifth, and last can also name me.

> Ele

also

> Nel, Mel, and Lin are other three letter nicknames for Emmeline that could be formed in a similar fashion.

Comment: +1 This is a really great guess! But you're right, it's not what I had in mind.

Comment: OK so I will keep on thinking :)

Answer (score 2):

May be you are

> ODD

why?
My name is the first, third, and last of my name

> O(first letter) + D(third letter) + D (last letter)

Or first, fifth, and sixth; that is quite all the same

> O(first letter) + D(fifth letter counting circularly) + D(sixth circularly)

Take first, second, sixth, and again you will see

> O(first) + D(second) + D(circularly sixth)

My first, fifth, and last can also name me.

> O(first) + D(fifth circularly) + D(last)

Comment: Good thinking; however, I am not counting circularly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> Assistant

My name is the first, third, and last of my name,

> First third and last letters are AST, which can be the abbreviation for assistant.

Or first, fifth, and sixth; that is quite all the same.

> First, fifth, and sixth letters are AST.

Take first, second, sixth, and again you will see:

> First, second, and sixth letters are AST.

My first, fifth, and last can also name me.

> First, fifth, and last letters are AST.

Comment: Nice, but how does it fit with the hint?

Comment: i don't think it does ha. oh well.